# How to resize canvasjs chart when its container's size changes dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, canvasjs

First look at this example https://codepen.io/merajahmed/pen/PJaeWR

```js
window.onload = function () {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
 animationEnabled: true,
 exportEnabled: true,
 theme: "light1", // "light1", "light2", "dark1", "dark2"
 title:{
  text: "Simple Column Chart with Index Labels"
 },
 data: [{
  type: "column", //change type to bar, line, area, pie, etc
  //indexLabel: "{y}", //Shows y value on all Data Points
  indexLabelFontColor: "#5A5757",
  indexLabelPlacement: "outside",
  dataPoints: [
   { x: 10, y: 71 },
   { x: 20, y: 55 },
   { x: 30, y: 50 },
   { x: 40, y: 65 },
   { x: 50, y: 92, indexLabel: "Highest" },
   { x: 60, y: 68 },
   { x: 70, y: 38 },
   { x: 80, y: 71 },
   { x: 90, y: 54 },
   { x: 100, y: 60 },
   { x: 110, y: 36 },
   { x: 120, y: 49 },
   { x: 130, y: 21, indexLabel: "Lowest" }
  ]
 }]
});
chart.render();

}
```

```css
.sidebar {
    background-color: black;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.sidebar h1 {
    color: white;
}

.portfolio {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 150px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    
    -moz-transition: left 0.5s ease;
    transition: left 0.5s ease;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
   display: none;
}

input:checked ~ .portfolio { 
    left: 0;
}

input:checked ~ label {
    left: 0;
}

label {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
    
    -moz-transition: left 0.5s ease;
    transition: left 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrap">
    <input id="slide-sidebar" type="checkbox" role="button" />
        <label for="slide-sidebar"><span>close</span></label>
    <div class="sidebar"><h1>Settings</h1></div>
    <div class="portfolio">
      
      <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to resize chart to full width when I click close button, but chart width does not changes.
Since there is animation between resizing the chart container, I want chart to take full width of its container during animation period. Means, Chart should grow/shrink its width during animation.

Answer (score 1):

The function that renders the chart is triggered by the `onload` event.

Simply extract that function definition, name it, for example, `render`, and trigger that same function for the `onresize` event.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JrZvQy

```
window.onload = render;
window.onresize = render;
```

Comment: @MerajAhmed Added code to trigger the render function when clicking on the close button.  It's a trivial example using `setTimeout`, but it should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But it re-render the chart. Its size does not changes during animation. If you try to resize the browser window, the chart resize automatically without re-rendering in my codepen. I want same effect here.

Comment: I think you should have enough to figure it out.